# Android Studio Internal Error

Tags: android

I started Android Studio and this appeared. Can someone tell me why it appeared and, if it is possible, how can I fix it?[image]

Comment: Yeah that's an internal IDE crash. Can you try uninstalling and re-installing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is with one of the third party plugins that you installed that seems to crash the app. The best way to get around it is completely uninstalled android studio and reinstall it